# How to set an alarm on dynamic date and time?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

Android 2.1

code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("message", header);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

When I **don’t** set a date-time and just *add a few seconds it works perfectly*.

But when I do set a date & time (I get the data as an answer from a different activity), it doesn’t work and I tripple checked that the data I’m getting is the correct one.

Any advices on what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the block of code that returns the data from a different activity? Do you tell this activity that data has changed?

Comment: I should have mentioned that this entire code block takes place on the 'onActivityResult' function, thanks

Comment: Month for Calendar is `0 to 11`, If you are getting month value as Jan=1 and Dec=12 then change it to `month-1` while setting it in calendar object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can be the only problem in your code as you said,

> When i dont set a date & time and just add a few seconds it works
>   perfectly.

You are getting different values in variable like `month,date,year` and setting them to `Calendar` object.

FYI :**The calendar object take months as January = 0 and December = 11 ,**

and i doubt you are getting them as *Jan=1 and Dec=12*, So you are unknownly *setting date of next month in Alarm* to trigger.

Check the value of month what you are getting and apply `cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);` and then it will work.

---

If you have written that Alarm code in loop then do take care to pass unique id each time in `PendingIntent` instead of one static value.

Comment: Thank you, all i had to do is cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month -1); like you said and it worked, thank you so much! ;-D

Comment: Never mind I also did the same mistake, that's just because either we are in hurry, or we ignore reading java :P